# How to get real time update using C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get real time update in firestore. The collection is "Users", it has different document of number. When I try to fellow Firebase Documentation to write the code but it list out all the document, not just newly added one. I use this code bellow:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        byte[] bytes = Properties.Resources.json;
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", tempFilePath);
    FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("db");
    Query userQuery = db.Collection("Users");
    FirestoreChangeListener listener = userQuery.Listen(snapshot =>
    {
        foreach (DocumentChange change in snapshot.Changes)
        {
            if (change.ChangeType.ToString() == "Added")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("New user: {0}", change.Document.Id);
            }
            else if (change.ChangeType.ToString() == "Modified")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Modified user: {0}", change.Document.Id);
            }
            else if (change.ChangeType.ToString() == "Removed")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Removed user: {0}", change.Document.Id);
            }
        }
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output is:

```
New user: 0
New user: 1
New user: 123
New user: 2
New user: 3
New user: 4
New user: 5
New user: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior: Firestore SDK synchronize the state of the data, not just the state changes. So the first time you read the `Users` collection the SDK gets all user documents, and since those are all new to that client, it raises them as newly `Added`.

If you only want to read documents that are new, you have to have some way to detect what "new" means (e.g. having a `createdAt` field in the document) and then [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to only request documents that are new.

Comment: How to do that can you help me

Comment: First off: is it clear from my answer why you get `New user` for each user document, rather than only for changes? And is it also clear how extra fields and queries could address that? ---  If so, I linked the documentation on querying, which includes code samples in C#. I recommend reading that, and trying to make it work yourself. If you run into problems there, edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean).